# Iphone maps direction question

Tags: iphone, maps, directions

In the iPhone maps application under directions, if I try to search for directions with current location and the destination being a place ex:Shell gas station, sometimes it returns the result of the Shell station closest to my location. At other times this returns the address in some other state in the US. This happens randomly.

Any clues why this happens or any way to get around it ?

Comment: use the latitude on longitude of your current position to the lat and lon of the gas station

Answer (score 0):

Searching for a point of interest (POI) in the Maps application tries to use the region defined by the visible map area to search. If that is too large an area, it uses your last known location. If you'd like it to search for shell gas stations near you, touch the 'current location' button and then do the search.

Comment: is there a way to programatically reduce the scope of the map, while we launch it from our app